# Binding user control visibility to valueconverter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I do have a ValueConverter that works fine on elements e.g. like a STACKPANEL. The Method User.OwnsRight(Int32) returns true or false.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(System.Windows.Visibility))]
public class ConverterUserRightVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bxSuite.Base.Objects.User locUser = (bxSuite.Base.Objects.User)value;

        if (parameter == null) return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        if (locUser == null) return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        if (locUser.OwnsRight(System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter)))
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Windows.Visibility locVisibility = (System.Windows.Visibility)value;
        if (locVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden || locVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So this XAML works great:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=User, Converter={StaticResource ConverterUserRightVisibility}, ConverterParameter=4}"></StackPanel>
```

But if i do bind the Visibility of one of my UserControls to this Converter, the Converter doesn't even get fired. The UserControl itself works fine.

```
<my:MenuButtonLarge Visibility="{Binding Path=User, Converter={StaticResource ConverterUserRightVisibility}, ConverterParameter=4}"/>
```

Any ideas why? Any help appreciated! Thanks a lot.

EDIT: i've tried another Converter simply setting text on a Label control. Works fine, but if i use it on a Textproperty (dependency property) of a usercontrol the Converter with the ConverterParameter doesn't get fired? What am I missing?

Comment: Even if you change the value of `User`? What about `Binding.Mode`?

Comment: how do you set the data context?

Comment: No, sorry. Changes of `User` work for StackPanel, no effects on UserControl. Also `Binding.Mode` doesn't change a thing.

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in Window using the UserControl